# Find all and delete in VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop, excel-2010

I am looking for a way to find all - in a column in VBA, store them or and delete the rows?

Here is what I can use to find and delete a single row.  But I need to find all of the dashes.

```
Dim A as Long

    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="-", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
     A = ActiveCell.Row
     Range(A).Delete
```

I thought about a loop but I don't know how many times to run the iteration as the number of dashes will vary.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Update- I'm not sure how to do mini markdown and make it readable so here is the updated code.

I keep getting the following error:  'ObjectVariable or With block Variable not set'

```
Dim LastRow As Long

'Find the last used row in a Column: column A
 With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 End With

'
 With Worksheets(5).Range("c1:c1500")
    Set c = .Find("-", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Value = "John"
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> LastRow
    End If
End With
```

Comment: here is a good example of using `Do..While` loop with `Find` method: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

Comment: See code updates in original post.  @simoco I have not quite got the hang of mini-Markdown formatting yet  Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you edit your question with this code, please) It's unreadeble in comments:) and also show plesase in what line of code are you getting an error

Comment: Error is in the "Loop While line"

Comment: try to change `c.Address <> LastRow` to `c.Address <> firstAddress`

Comment: can't reproduce your error

Comment: Tried that first as it was directly out of the example and it gave the same error.  I figured the issue was that firstaddress was not defined as a variable so tried the new code.

Comment: Interesting.  Wonder if something else then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47256/discussion-between-simoco-and-sasusmc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follows up from chat, this code is working:

```
Sub test()
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rngToDelete As Range

    With Worksheets(5).Range("c1:c1500")
       Set c = .Find("-", LookIn:=xlValues)
       If Not c Is Nothing Then
           firstAddress = c.Address
           Do
               If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                  Set rngToDelete = c
               Else
                  Set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, c)
               End If
               Set c = .FindNext(c)
               If c Is Nothing Then Exit Do
           Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
       End If
    End With

    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help @simoco, that was one of the final pieces to a much larger macro.